# Не выводит Японские символы в консоль

Tags: c++, локаль

Недавно ввел практику использования `w`- типы (без понятия как они точно называются по этому назвал их по приставке), Русские и Английские символы он выводит хорошо, а вот Японские он не выводит (хотя вроде бы они есть в юникоде) не выводит ничего (Хирагана, Катакана, Кандзи)

```
#include <io.h> 
#include <iostream> //debug
#include <fcntl.h>
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"Hello こんいちわ Привет. Goodbye さようなら Пока. ひらがな カタカナ 感じ 「」【】（）" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ОС? шрифты консольные под эти символы установлены?

Comment: `#nclude "wchar.h"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выберите в консоли шрифт `MS Gothic`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось максимально глупым, дело в том что шрифт в консоли не поддерживал японские символы.

Простите за излишнее внимание.