# Почему в программах на Linux не нужно вызывать setlocale, а на Windows - нужно?

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

Почему в программах на `C` и `C++` на `Linux` любые строки выводятся, как надо, а на `Windows` обязательно нужно вызывать метод `setlocale`, чтобы строки на определённом языке выводились правильно?

Comment: *"на Windows обязательно нужно вызывать метод setlocale"* - ничего подобного, Windows начиная с Microsoft Layer for Unicode on Windows 95, 98 имеет встроенную поддержку юникода. А Linux же до сих пор существует в режиме ascii-совместимости (точнее с использованием posix portable character set), и вывод юникода из приложений зачастую может быть невозможен в принципе без соответствующего допиливания системы.

Comment: @user7860670 это в каком дистрибутиве линукса в 2020 году вы такое увидели?

Comment: @gbg Во всех без исключения.

Comment: Как обычно, самые интересные тонкости где-то в комментариях)

Comment: @user7860670 вы искажаете факты. В 90% случаев пользователь использует графическую программу-эмулятор терминала, которая работает в юникоде.

Comment: @gbg ну технически вроде бы, насколько я понимаю, стандартный utf-8 является надмножеством этого самого posix portable character set)

Comment: @user7860670 а поддержка юникода в венде реализуется через такие лютейшие костыли, что лучше бы ее там не было. Наличие фактически двух WINAPI с 16 битным юникодом внутри, который все равно не поддерживает все символы, это ужас для интернациональных приложений.

Comment: @gbg Ничего подобного. В 90% случаев установка компонентов и настройка окружения для работы с не-posix кодировками не производится. То, что вы описали - это скорее то, что происходит при установке какой-нибудь локализованной десктопной бубунты. Что касается двух API - это было компромиссное решение, а сейчас из них нужно только одно.

Comment: Не понял про нелокализованные и недесктопные виндоузы, в которых всё работает из коробки. Это какие?

Comment: @user7860670 в линуксах (практически во всех современных) локаль спрашивает при установке (или по умолчанию выставляет utf8 под конкретную страну) и проблем не возникает. Даже в локализированных бубунтах (ну может кроме совсем наколенных решениям). Для винды хочется увидеть минимальный исходник, который будет не в кодировке 866 без троганья локали и при этом выводил нормально кириллицу.

Comment: @KoVadim В линуксах установка обычно происходит не в интерактивном режиме, и если специально не заморочиться с генерацией локали и настройкой окружения, то так и останется посикс. А вот и [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839637/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%AF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C/839643). Причем заметьте, что кодовая страница при выводе так и остается cp866, в чем можно убедиться, добавив проверку `assert(866 == GetConsoleOutputCP());`

Comment: @KoVadim А вообще можно в настройках системы выставить использование utf-8 и писать его в обычный `cout`.

Comment: @user7860670, ваш пример использует wcout. Будем учебники и методички переписывать?

Comment: @gbg Давно пора.

Comment: @user7860670  будет еще хуже, потому что UCS-16 создает иллюзию того, что со строкой можно работать как с массивом (ага, до первой суррогатной пары) и вкусно кушает память при работе с чисто английскими текстами.

Comment: @user7860670 Ваши сообщения как то совсем трольские. "установка происходит не в интерактивном режиме".... что?. Дальше. Пример устанавливает режим перекодирования символов для конкретного дескриптора. Конечно, другие функции будут выдавать все что Вам хочется. Плюс опять же, как только пользовать заиспользует string/char - может получить в лоб. ПС такими костылями и я могу выводить в консоль красиво. А вот без костылей.... Выставить в настройках винды utf-8 - о, это знатно можно потролить админов и других пользователей.

Comment: Что значит "совсем трольские"? Поставить десктопную бубунту один раз - еще куда ни шло, кому в здравом уме придет в голову массово раскатывать линукс в интерактивном режиме? *"Пример устанавливает режим перекодирования символов для конкретного дескриптора."* - нет, никакого перекодирования не происходит. А кодовая страница при выводе так и остается cp866, в чем можно убедиться, добавив проверку `assert(866 == GetConsoleOutputCP());`, я же написал выше. "Как только пользовать заиспользует string/char" ...то при выводе и при работе с разными функциями winapi это подразумевает отказ от юникода.

Comment: @user7860670 так и венду на предприятиях как правило раскатывают не руками. Однако мы говорим о конкретной истории - студент пишет консольное приложение. На руках у него машина либо с вендой, либо с убунтой (90%), или с центосом/федорой, которые он скорее всего сам же и установил, выбрав при установке русскую локаль.

Теперь у него на линуксе все хорошо, а на венде - мусор. Вот он и задал вопрос.

Comment: @user7860670 Вы определитесь где Linux , где Windows. В Linux нету функции `GetConsoleOutputCP()` что мне проверять в Linux ? В Linux локаль по умолчанию ставится в UTF-8 и файлы создаются в кодировки UTF-8 поэтому все корректно работает. А в Windows в консоли одна кодировка, в файле другая . поэтому нужно постоянно следить где какая кодировка , что бы было корректное отображение символов.

Comment: @user7860670 для массовой раскатки админы готовят правильную сборку/конфиги, где прописывают все, что нужно. и нет проблем. _setmode устанавливает дословно "Sets the file translation mode." - что можно перевести как перекодирование/перевод.

Comment: @KoVadim Вот именно. А локали обычно не входят в перечень нужного и не включаются в конечный образ, соответственно остается посикс по-умолчанию.

Comment: @Yaroslav А что вы собираетесь проверять на linux? Пример выше же был для "винды хочется увидеть минимальный исходник". "В Linux локаль по умолчанию ставится в UTF-8" - как раз по-умолчанию там POSIX... Да, постоянно следить за кодировкой - утомительное занятие, однако подразумевать, что в linux везде по-умолчанию работает utf-8 - большое заблуждение.

Comment: @user7860670, в *nix абсолютно не важно какая локаль у пользовательской программы, если она делает вывод в utf-8 и эмулятор терминала работает с utf-8 (а эта установка у них по умолчанию)

Comment: @user7860670 "А локали обычно не входят в перечень нужного " - я думаю, Вы будете искать любые пути, что бы только доказать, что в линуксе кодировка не та. Но к чему Вы видете? что тысячи вопросов в стиле "у меня каракули/иероглифы в консоли, что мне делать", просто надуманы?

Comment: @KoVadim Мне представляется, что тема практического использования юникода в С/C++ на самом деле очень сложна, а те, кто распространяют "простые" советы вроде писать в cout в utf-8 с аргументами вида "ну на моей бубунте же везде utf-8 и все работает" или "на windows надо использовать setlocale", занимаются прямо-таки вредительством.

Comment: ну так, а что Вы предлагаете в качестве решения?

Comment: @KoVadim ну например, в режиме терминала (Ctrl+Alt+F1) (по крайней мере в моём Kali Linux) выводятся только английские буквы. Я не понял всего, что тут писали вы и другие люди, но если бы в линуксе по умолчанию стояла кодировка utf-8, то в режиме терминала должны были бы выводиться все символы, а этого не происходит. С чем это может быть связано? Могу задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия - думаю, Вам нужно сформулировать точно вопрос и создать его. Потому что пока оно выглядит как решение проблемы X-Y. Но скорее всего по Ctrl-Alt-F1 Вы запускаете виртуальную консоль, а там нужно настраивать шрифты. То есть, кириллица выводится, но пустым местом. Но обычно в оконном режиме все запускают эмулятор терминала и не парятся. А там обычно все ок.

Comment: @user7860670 Сейчас в Linux `LANG=C or LANG=POSIX or LANG=UTF-8` это синонимы и при установки любой из этих локалей , и при условии что  в системе установлены шрифты `ru.UTF-8` кириллица будет отображаться корректно. Просто не забывайте что локале это не только символы , но и еще отображение формата времени, цифр , денежных знаков и т.д. И даже если локаль установить `en.UTF-8`. кириллица будет отображаться корректно (при наличии шрифтов) , а вот формат времени будет другой нежели чем `ru.UTF-8`

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Не отображение кодировки utf-8 связано с тем что у Вас не установлены нужные шрифты для отображения всех символов utf-8. И если вы в программе попытаетесь отобразить вот такой массив `char array[] = {0xe3, 0x81, 0x9d, 0x00}` В полне возможно у вас ничего не получится , но если вы установите японские шрифты , то у вас отобразится иероглиф.

Comment: @Yaroslav я задал отдельный вопрос на эту тему.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Потому что в линуксе в терминале юникод и в исходниках такой же юникод.

А в русской венде консоль до сих пор по умолчанию работает в CP866, эмулируя 286 машину бухгалтера из 1994 года.

А редактор кода, которым вы пользуетесь, скорее всего работает в CP1251. Отсюда путаница и мусор вместо букв.

Comment: Ответ минусуют, но критики я не вижу, так что пока я его приму.

Comment: Ответ верный, а минусуют за петросянство)

Comment: Минусаторы и удаляторы приглашаются в комментарии с опровержениями фактов, изложенных в ответе.

Comment: Наверное, стоит добавить, что «до сих пор *по умолчанию* работает ...»

Comment: Ну да, как раз setlocale это поведение и меняет

Comment: просто нужно было ещё упомянуть и о cp1251. И очень весело, когда все три кодировки соберутся в одном месте. (то есть, текстовый файл с данными в cp1251, консоль в 866 и код в ucs-16).

Comment: Вы искажаете факты. *"в линуксе в терминале юникод и в исходниках такой же юникод"* - это еще бабушка на двое сказала. В терминале может быть что угодно. А в исходниках рекомендуется использовать исключительно ppcs (тем же бустом). Терминал в Windows выводит юникод, независимо от режима работы и не требуя `setlocale`, даже при работе в том же CP866. Существует проблема, что в используемом шрифте по-умолчанию шрифте может не оказаться нужных символов, прежде всего азиатских.

Comment: Тот же блокнот уже давно по-умолчанию сохраняет документы в кодировке utf-8.

Comment: @user7860670 вы постите прямую ложь. Весь терминал работает в CP866, как на ввод, так и на вывод. Если бы он работал в юникоде, не требовалось бы никаких переключений для того, чтобы программ получала символы в юникоде с клавиатуры, а выводимые ей символы бы интерпретировались как символы юникода, а не CP866.

Comment: @gbg Так а переключение и не требуется... Вот для ввода - это да, без переключения не обойтись.

Comment: так же стоит упомянуть, что даже в наш 2020 некоторые люди в Linux настраивают koi-8ru и у них могут быть подобные проблемы также. Но обычно они о них узнают немного раньше, чем добираются до с/с++.

Comment: @user7860670 правильно ли я понимаю, что если на современной windows-10 запустить консольную программу, которая пишет "Привет, мир!" в utf-8, все выведется правильно?

Comment: @KoVadim - это надо ОЧЕНЬ СИЛЬНО постараться, чтобы выкопать такой дистр, в котором эта опция при установке не зарыта крайне глубоко.

Comment: На современной windows-10 можно запустить консольную программу, которая пишет "Привет, мир!" используя 16-битный wchar_t, все выведется правильно. А если хочется выводить именно в utf-8, то можно сменить режим по-умолчанию с CP866 на UTF-8 (имеется ввиду в системе, а не в приложении). При выводе оно все равно будет преобразовываться в 16-битный wchar_t.

Comment: Так, Ну а редакторы кода, как правило, работают все же в CP1251 или UTF8, которые не совпадают с UCS-16 и отсюда мусор.

Вы же активно утверждаете, что никаких настроек делать не нужно, что является ложным утверждением.

Comment: wchar_t - это не кодировка. в винде используется ucs-16 (возможно плюс суррогатные пары). Но код хотелось бы увидеть

Comment: О, эти суррогатные пары в середине 2000х привели к скандалу с какой-то не то индианкой, не то тайкой, у которой в имени был такой символ и скайп не мог его корректно обработать.

Comment: У меня на рабочей машине не `1251` а [`Active code page: 932`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxiui.png).